# Spring Cloud Config Server - Cannot detect Git Local File

Tags: java, spring, git, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a problem about getting properties file from Git.

I've done some settings for defining git local repo shown below.

1. Open Git Bash
2. mkdir git-localconfig-repo
3. cd git-localconfig-repo
4. git init
5. git add
6. git commit -m "Message"
7. git branch -> master

git-localconfig-repo is located under C:/Users/Username/

Here is the **application.properties** file of **Spring Cloud Config** shown below

```
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///C:/Users/Username/git-localconfig-repo (I use Windows)
```

Here is the another services' properties file shown below

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
spring.application.name=limits-service
```

When I tried to send a request to `http://localhost:8888/limit-service/default` , I got this json result shown below.

```
{"name": "limit-service","profiles": ["default"],"label": null,"version": "5161fd2bf848e99e7447f4bd95f4dcf914f97066","state": null,"propertySources": []}
```

Here are errors appearing on the console in Spring Cloud Config shown below.

```
org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchLabelException: No such label: main
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref main cannot be resolved
```

I defined `spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master` or `spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main` in **application.properties** file of Spring Cloud Config but nothing changed.

I defined **master** and then restart Config server and then restart limit service

Here is the **application.properties** file of **Spring Cloud Config** shown below

```
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///C:/Users/Noyan/git-localconfig-repo
```

Here is the console result shown below.

```
2022-09-07 14:16:31.110  WARN 2096 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] .c.s.e.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository : Could not merge remote for master remote: null
2022-09-07 14:16:31.134  INFO 2096 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: Config resource 'file [C:\Users\Noyan\git-localconfig-repo\limits-service.properties]' via location 'file:/C:/Users/Noyan/git-localconfig-repo/'
```

When I tried to send a request to `http://localhost:8888/limit-service/default` , I got this json result shown below.

```
{
    "name": "limit-service",
    "profiles": [
        "default"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": "5161fd2bf848e99e7447f4bd95f4dcf914f97066",
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": []
}
```

Here is the console result shown below.

```
2022-09-07 14:16:31.110  WARN 2096 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] .c.s.e.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository : Could not merge remote for master remote: null
2022-09-07 14:16:31.134  INFO 2096 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: Config resource 'file [C:\Users\Noyan\git-localconfig-repo\limits-service.properties]' via location 'file:/C:/Users/Noyan/git-localconfig-repo/'
2022-09-07 14:18:18.698  WARN 2096 --- [nio-8888-exec-6] .c.s.e.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository : Could not merge remote for master remote: null
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @spencergibb Spring Boot version is 2.7.3 and Github version is 2.37.3.

Comment: If I’m not wrong I’ve faced the same issue. You have to define the label also in the client. The property is `spring.cloud.config.label` and you have to hit `http://localhost:8888/limit-service/default/master`

Comment: @Pp88 How should I define `spring.cloud.config.label` ? Is it possible to write the answer if you don't mind?

Comment: When you hit `http://localhost:8888/limit-service/default/master` are the properties downloaded? do you have in your master branch a file named `limit-service-default.yaml`?

Comment: @spencergibb I have a same issue. Have you ever fixed it? Here is my link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75277601/spring-boot-microservices-config-server-cannot-fetch-property-file-adding-pro